# running an applet embedded page from swt browser(mozilla)

Tags: java, applet, swt

I am trying to open a applet embedded webpage using the swt browser and getting the following error ...stuck here ..can anybody help

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/services/Service
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ivb.coep.vtu.plc.OpenBrowser.<init>(OpenBrowser.java:33)
    at com.ivb.coep.vtu.plc.OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.services.Service
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Browser support for applets varies by platform:
>
> Windows: As of Eclipse/SWT 3.5, applets can be viewed in a Browser if
>   all of the following conditions are met:
>
> 1) For Browsers created with style SWT.NONE, the installed IE version
>   is 7.0 or newer
>
> 2) For Browsers created with style SWT.MOZILLA, the installed
>   XULRunner version is 1.9.2.x or 3.6.x
>
> 3) The installed Java plug-in is Sun JRE 1.6u10 or newer, with the
>   Next Generation Java Plug-in enabled (this plug-in is enabled by
>   default when the JRE is installed)
>
> 4) The application is launched with the same JRE that provides the
>   installed Java plug-in
>
> 5) The application adds the JRE's plugin.jar, deploy.jar and
>   javaws.jar jars to the JRE's boot classpath. For example, to launch
>   eclipse: eclipse -vmargs -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\lib\javaws.jar"
>
> Linux (Mozilla): Applets can be viewed with Mozilla-based Browsers as
>   long as the Mozilla Java plug-in is found at runtime.
>
> OS X (WebKit): Applets cannot be viewed with WebKit-based Browsers on
>   OS X because the launching of a JRE to execute the applet collides
>   with the JRE that is running the application.

Reference: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserapplets

Check the above link and validate all the stated criteria in that page for applets to run on an swt browser. I'm guessing some JAR files are missing from your application's classpath.

Especially this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/services/Service`. This class belongs to deploy.jar.

Comment: i have chk this and downloaded the correct version of  xulrunner i.e Mozilla Xul Runner 1.9.2.26 but now when i register it through cmd it does not give any error but while running the program i am getting exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.ivb.coep.vtu.plc.OpenBrowser.<init>(OpenBrowser.java:18)
 at com.ivb.coep.vtu.plc.OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:39)

Comment: Check this http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howdetectmozilla and this http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner .Try  starting the application with explicit path to xulrunner, like this `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/path/to/XulRunner`